# Which is the best way to study the odoo development and customization ( structure and flow )

Tags: odoo-8, openerp-8

I am a starter in odoo development and customization. Nothing is easy to study fast. some dedications and patience should be needed. Can anybody suggest a best way to study the odoo development and customization? I mean, can anybody suggest a good way of understand the odoo complete structure and how it can be customized? It will be thankful if anybody can suggest a good URL's or tutorial suggestions to get into this odoo development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid tutorial requests aren't on topic on Stack Overflow, and the community may vote to close the question for that reason. A search for `best Odoo tutorials` seems to turn up useful material, though. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The first step starts with the installation of the odoo. You will find here step by step sequence to install the odoo https://www.techreceptives.com/blog/business-4/post/step-by-step-guide-to-install-odoo-v10-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-138

Now if it's up to you, that what you want to customize in odoo. i.e
You want to create the odoo Website, New Module, want to work with API and web services and much more. Here at this below link, you will find the help for the any of you interested area. 
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/

I found this link http://odootechnical.com/odoo-module-structure/  best sources to understand the structure of the odoo Module

Still if you are in confusion or not getting what to do, just comment here I will try my best to help you.